# How do I count unique combinations for each element in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

I have a dataset with two columns - student_login and reviewer_login. A person can be both a student and an reviewer. We need to find a unique number of pairs, regardless of the person's role. For example, the pairs login_1, login_2 and login_2, login_1 must be counted once. In the final dataset I want to get the number of unique contacts for each person.

My dataset looks like:

| student_login | reviewer_login |
| --- | --- |
| login_1 | login_2 |
| login_2 | login_1 |
| login_1 | login_3 |
| login_2 | Login_3 |

The result dataset should look like this:

| login | unique_contacts |
| --- | --- |
| login_1 | 2 |
| login_2 | 2 |
| login_1 | 2 |

Is there any functions to implement this?

Answer (score 2):

**Code**

After `concat` df and dataframe with reverse order of the columns in df,

use `groupby` + `nunique` function.

```
cols = ['login', 'unique_contacts']
out = (pd.concat([df.set_axis(cols, axis=1), df.set_axis(cols[::-1], axis=1)])
       .groupby('login', as_index=False)['unique_contacts'].nunique()
)
```

out

```
    login   unique_contacts
0   login_1 2
1   login_2 2
2   login_3 2
```

---

**Example Code**

```
import pandas as pd   
data = {'student_login': ['login_1', 'login_2', 'login_1', 'login_2'],
        'reviewer_login': ['login_2', 'login_1', 'login_3', 'login_3']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```